# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services permissions

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, permissions

I'm having trouble with SQL Server 2008 (Express with Advanced Services) Reporting Services permissions.  I'm running this on Vista Ultimate at home - standalone machine with no servers, no domain or active directory.

When I go to the ReportServices site, I get this:

> The permissions granted to user
>   '*localmachine*\Scott' are insufficient for
>   performing this operation.
>   (rsAccessDenied)

I don't remember having a problem at the office with SQL Standard on Windows 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running IE as admin and then going to the page. Then under settings add your user and give it permissions. You should be able to run IE not as admin after that. This worked for me using SSRS 2005 under vista.

If not that, then check which user account the service is running as.

See the MSDN page about [How to Configure Reporting Services on Vista and Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx)

Comment: Strange.  I had already tried logging in as administrator, but that didn't work.  Running IE as admin did work.  Is this documented?

Comment: Found the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630430.aspx

Comment: Cool :) Incorporated your link into the answer, so other people can see it straight away.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried running IE as admin then going to the page, but I'm still getting the access denied error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Phillip Wells said: "I have the same problem. I've tried running IE as admin then going to the page, but I'm still getting the access denied error. Any suggestions?"

I also had this problem. I ran IE as Administrator but still got the access denied error. It seems that IE still did not run as Administrator.

Then I tried to use another browser (I tried Google Chrome) as Administrator. Then boom! The Home Page of SQL Server Reporting Services Manager is shown up with the tab Properties. I click it. I add my account to become the Content Manager. Then I open IE as usual (not as Administrator), and then I can browse and manage the SSRS Manager site.

Comment: This (using a browser besides IE) did the trick for me. Also remember to give your user permissions both to SSRS (Site Settings > Security) as well as the Home folder (Folder Settings).

Answer (score 0):

Try with administrator permissions, you run Internet Explorer with administrator, I attached three images with that issue and the solution. I had the same issue in w8.
Good Look.