# ADODB SQL Server connection not working only in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, adodb

Got a bit of an odd problem.

This code works fine in every other browser, just not in IE9. Standard ADODB connection string being used:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Server=localhost\sqlexpress;Database=DB;uid=DBuser;password=DBPassword;MultipleActiveRecordSets=true;
```

Executed thus:

```
Dim dbGlobal
Set dbGlobal = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbGlobal.Open sConnectionString
```

In every browser this works and the application then goes on to load, in IE9 I get the following error message back:

-2147467259: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. Are you running on the same server when you test with IE9 as other browsers?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible either. The code you posted here runs completely independent from the browser. It's server-side code, not client-side code. Are you sure you didn't meet your connection limit using your other browsers?

Comment: I don't see how it is possible either! The SQL Server is a SQL Server 2008 R2 (X64) Express running on my local. The REALLY weird thing, is that if I change the server in the connection string to be the SQL Server 2008 R2 server that my whole company uses, IE9 connects fine. So the problem definitely exists between IE9, my local IIS and my local SQL Server.

The application is a classic ASP application, running in IIS 7.5, with Windows Authentication against a local admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Well with the help of the following answer on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/a/260861/418151), I managed to get a work around. As per that answer I tried running IE as admin and now it connects fine to the SQL Server!

I can only assume that in the last week or two I've installed some Windows Update that has slightly altered the permissions of SQL Server and/or IE9.

Still got no idea why exactly I now have to run IE as admin in order to connect to SQL Server!?

Comment: Even more digging around shows that it seems to be IE's Protected Mode that is blocking the connection...